# How to have users select multiple geospatial locations in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geospatial, postgis

I'm building an application using Ruby on Rails and PostGIS that allows users to find affordable housing. I plan to have the users select multiple locations on a map as acceptable locations. However, the Postgis adapter only allows users to select one location (lat, long) and input a radius. How do I allow users to select multiple points on a map?

Comment: Kindly include snippets of code you've worked with so far. The community can help you refactor it as needed better then.

Answer (score 1):

Using ST_Collect of PostGIS

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html

It is a collection of geometries. There are Ruby APIs for PostGIS as well.